# Understanding predict.gbm output for multinomial classification

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution, boosting

I am using `gbm` package for multinomial classification.

Here is an extract of my code (where target is the variable I want to predict, learning the matrix over which I train my model and validate the matrix over which I compute classification).

```
gbmModel <- gbm(target ~ param1 + param2 + param3, data = learning, 
             ntrees = 100, distribution = "multinomial")
predictionMatrix <- predict(gbmModel, newdata = validate, n.trees = 50)
```

From what I understood, the output (predictionMatrix) is a matrix returning the probability for each level of target. However, when viewing this matrix, I have this kind of results (target has much more levels).

```
    target1 target2 target3
1   0.1298  1.7167  0.1112
2  -0.0045  0.0016  1.8562
3   0.0234 -0.0042 -0.0053
```

I have no problem selecting the highest value for each observation. However, my question is : why are these "probabilities" exceeding range [0,1] ? How come they are negative ? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? `predict.gbm` does not by default return probabilities, but the linear predictor (same as `predict.glm`), to get probabilities you need to run it with `type = "response`.

Comment: I thought this worked only for Bernoulli and Poisson distributions according to the documentation... Whatever, I tested it and it works. Thanks !